# how to run a script before execute a dbus-send command?

Tags: suspend, lubuntu, d-bus, hook

I have the following problem: on lubuntu 16.04 I can send the laptop to sleep (suspend on RAM) using a hook script to switch to a virtual teminal before to suspend and reswitching out from a vt after suspend
/etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt

```
cat /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt
#!/bin/sh

# Switch to a VC before suspending and back after resume

case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
            chvt 7
        ;;
        suspend|hibernate)
            chvt 1
        ;;
esac
```

but when I execute (and also the lxdesession-logout does) the dbus command

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement  /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement  org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Suspend
```

the hook script is not executed and the system does not wake-up properly (blank screen and need to reboot from vt1)